# onClick message causes unwanted refreshing of the page

Tags: elm

I'm trying to build a website in Elm and it includes a couple links to change the language:

```
div [ class "language" ][ a [ class englishClass, onClick (ChangeLanguage English) ] [ text "EN" ]
                        , a [ class germanClass, onClick (ChangeLanguage German) ] [ text "DE" ]
                        , a [ class italianClass, onClick (ChangeLanguage Italian) ] [ text "IT" ]
                        ]
```

My Update looks like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ...  -- Stuff for URLs

        ChangeLanguage language ->
            ( { model | language = language }
            , Cmd.none
            )

type Msg
    = LinkClicked Browser.UrlRequest
    | UrlChanged Url.Url
    | ChangeLanguage Language
```

This is my model:

```
type alias Model =
    { key : Nav.Key
    , url : Url.Url
    , language : Language
    }
```

And this is my init function, which (at least in my mind) defaults to English as a language:

```
init : flags -> Url.Url -> Nav.Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ url key = ( Model key url English, Cmd.none )
```

**The problem:**

Whenever I click the links that change the language, they *do* seem to work: I see the language of the paragraphs in the page change, but then several unwanted things happen:

1. The page refreshes. Since I already saw the language change across the page, it's clear this is not needed so I'd like to avoid it.
2. As a consequence of 1, the viewport is brought all the way to the top of the page again.
3. The language changes to the default English again!

How could I avoid 1 (and thus 2) from happening?
And what am I missing to make it so the change is maintained across the site (at least when refreshing the page, since I haven't tried working with sessions or cookies yet)?

Comment: Why are you using `a` elements if you don't want to move to a new page or refresh the current one? Change the element type and this problem should go away.

Comment: Semantically, it's the most appropriate element I could think of. But there's no harm in changing it so I'll try doing that. Could you elaborate on what exactly causes this behaviour and how to override it (if possible)? If you do it as an answer and it solves the problem, I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: Another answer as to why I'm using `a` elements is that I assumed Elm would generate well-behaved HTML-like output. An `a` element without an href attribute does not cause any refresh or page change to occur, nor do `onClick` events on them or other elements cause it by themselves. This is my first Elm project which I'm using to explore the language, I don't have good knowledge of Elm's behaviour and idiosyncrasies yet, so I have to make assumptions especially where code is made to look like something else I'm already familiar with. @RobinZigmond

Comment: Apologies, I made an assumption which seems not to be justified. I assumed the behaviour you described was due to the use of `a`, and that an `a` tag without an `href` would generate a link to the same page (I've never tried this before in HTML because, well, what's the point of an anchor tag without an `href`). I certainly can't see anything else in your example that would cause the behaviour you described - but it appears I was wrong about the cause. But I still think it's daft to use `a` if you don't actually want a link - a `button` or even a `span` seems semantically more appropriate.

Comment: The point of an anchor tag without an href is to provide, well, an anchor, as a bookmark into a page. A URL to a page with `#something` will scroll to an anchor with `name='something'`. Now it's my turn to apologise though: when I tested I made a mistake in the code and changed the wrong part. Changing the right elements into *span*s does solve the code. Do you have any guess as to why `a` elements have this behaviour and whether it can be overridden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider this behaviour a bug in Elm, and have filed [an issue](https://github.com/elm/browser/issues/55) for it, as have [others](https://github.com/elm/browser/issues/34) with [associated PRs](https://github.com/elm/virtual-dom/pull/142). But in the year and a half since have received no attention from anyone in a position to actually do something about it, which is unfortunately par for the course with Elm.

The problem is that Elm "hijacks" `onClick` on `a` elements to create navigation events so that anchors can be handled inside Elm. When using `Browser.application`, clicking an `a` element will have Elm call `onUrlReuqest` with a value of `Browser.UrlRequest`, which will class the URL as either `Internal` or `External` and require you to make a decision on what to do with it.

The problem at the root of this is that omitting `href` will generate an `External` `UrlRequest` with the URL being an empty string. By default, and by the usual handling of `External`, this will tell the browser to load the URL as usual, thus refreshing the page. But it also suggests a possible workaround is to special-case `External ""`:

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UrlRequested (Browser.Internal _) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        UrlRequested (Browser.External "") ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )

        UrlRequested (Browser.External url) ->
            ( model, Browser.Navigation.load url )

        UrlChanged _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

Another workaround is to add `href="#"` to the `a` elements, which will correctly classify them as `Internal`

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the insight. I think I'll go with using `span` elements for now since I don't like meaningless attributes. Though accessibility is certainly impacted by not using `a` for clickable links. My issue with special-casing `External ""` is that I'm already sending my own message type with that onClick event, and I didn't expect it to inherit External's behaviour.